# Search after match in dynamic lines

Tags: perl

Dears,

I have the file below in the following format

```
Success|Filter passed|[invalid field]|[invalid field]|Id-350a875b087965e58cbe1f4a
Accept: text/plain, text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*, */*
Host: api2.tim.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Via: 1.1 
X-Forwarded-For: 144.22.98.123
X-Forwarded-Host:
X-Forwarded-Server:

Success|Success in calling policy shortcut|[invalid field]|[invalid field]|[invalid field]|Id-350a875b087965e58cbe1f4a|Call 'Set Request Message'|GET
Accept: text/plain, text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*, */*
Host: api2.tim.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Via: 1.1 api2.tim.com.br
X-Forwarded-For: 144.22.98.123
X-Forwarded-Host: 
X-Forwarded-Server: 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
```

I need to perform a search for the line that begins with the string "^ Success" and display all the items until there is a "^ Sucess" string again. 
Here is an example of what I need to display:

```
Success|Filter passed|[invalid field]|[invalid field]|Id-350a875b087965e58cbe1f4a
Accept: text/plain, text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*, */*
Host: api2.tim.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Via: 1.1 
X-Forwarded-For: 144.22.98.123
X-Forwarded-Host:
X-Forwarded-Server:
```

What happens is that the amount of lines below after the match is very dynamic.

What happens is that the amount of lines below the match is very dynamic and in the same file there may be several lines 
of the same match and I would need to display them also when the file is run.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Is there an empty line before the closing `Success`?

Comment: Crossposted to [Perlmonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1221457).

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a "paragraph mode". You change the input record separator, `$/` to read chunks of "multiline" text. This splits up your data on the double newline:

```
use v5.10;

$/ = "\n\n";

while( <INPUT> ) {
    chomp;
    say "==========\n$_\n----------\n";
    }
```

Start your program with that and try to do whatever else you're trying to do. In your next question you'll have the small demonstration program you need to get better help.

Comment: I think I'd use `$/ = ''` - just in case any extra blank lines sneaked in between the records.